# How to iterate over objects in array of array in angular

Tags: angularjs

I pushed few array of objects into an empty array which I then want to display on the html.

```
$scope.displaypersons = [
[{name: "abc"}],
[{name: "pqr"},{name: "lmn"},{name: "rst"}],
[{name: "uvw"},{name: "xyz"}]
]
```

In html

```
<div ng-repeat="person in displaypersons"> 
  {{person}}
  <!-- {{person.name}} doesn't work -->
</div>
```

But after iterating, I'm getting this way:.

```
[{"name": "abc"}]
[{"name": "pqr"},{"name": "lmn"},{"name": "rst"}]
[{"name": "uvw"},{"name": "xyz"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 2-dimensional array. Angular will only iterate the 1st dimension. You need `person[i].name` to get that attribute.

Or try:

```
<div ng-repeat="persons in displaypersons"> 
    <div ng-repeat="person in persons"> 
        {{person.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a 2-D array, you need to nest your ngRepeats in order to access the objects.

```
<div ng-repeat="personGroup in displaypersons">
  <div ng-repeat="person in personGroup">
    {{person.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom filter to turn your 2D array into a flat array.

```
angular.module('myApp').filter("flatten", function() {
     function flatten (arr) {
         return arr.reduce(function(a, b) {return a.concat(b)});
     };
     return flatten;
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="person in displaypersons | flatten"> 
     {{person.name}}
</div>
```